# Text Extraction Query

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have a text file similar to the example shown below:

```
139
text string
text string
text string
text string
text string
text string

139
fdghdfkljsghaksjgh
fdkdsjahgks
fklsdjghlksdjh
jksdgh

139

text string
text string
text string
text string
text string
text string
text string
text string

139

dfhsdglka
dfhglasd3489 57
sdauufh348977
3o487562348ryoius
85734uyf

139

text string
text string
text string
text string
text string
text string
text string

139

lksfh;klhdg;
dhfglsdhfg
jhdfgljasdhgf
dhfgkladhfg
hdgfla
fgjlad

139

text string
text string
text string
text string
text string
text string
text string
text string

139

dfhsdglka
dfhglasd3489 57
sdauufh348977
3o487562348ryoius
85734uyf

139

text string
text string
text string
text string
text string
text string
text string

139

lksfh;klhdg;
dhfglsdhfg
jhdfgljasdhgf
dhfgkladhfg
hdgfla
fgjlad
```

I wish to extract all the text between `139`-s which shows the block of text "text string" and copy it to another file, while ignoring the random characters (not to be copied). Also I do not want `139` to show up in the new file. The "text string" referred above indicates a block of text containing several paragraphs.

Comment: I thought of something. The task might become much easier if every 2nd, 4th, 6th, etc.. occurrence of 139 is replaced by something else, e.g. 391. Then the task would be much simpler.

Comment: What's the actual use? What have you tried yourself? You probably would need a loop and indeed, having different identifiers for the start and end would be helpful.

Comment: The use is that all the text collected from the page would serve as a sort of manual for me.  I am new to shell scripting. I tried egrep

Comment: The use is that all the text collected from the page would serve as a sort of manual for me. I am new to shell scripting. I tried egrep command that I got from this website itself. I simply donot know how to proceed.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/763470/how-to-search-a-text-file-for-strings-between-two-tokens-in-ubuntu-terminal-and          My query is similar to this query except in the fact that the data to be extracted is in the form of several paragraphs.

Comment: You could either try to write a regex that matches from the start of a paragraph to the end or you could use a loop. This isn't so much shell programing as regular programing ideas. As an example you could loop through each line and react to your markers by "collecting" the following lines or writing them to a (new) file.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner utilizing multiple perls and aspell (in order to identify random strings):

```
perl -0777 -ne 'while(m/(?<=139)(.*(\n)*)*(?=139)/g){print "$&\n";}' /path/to/file | \
perl -0777 -pe 's/139\n//g' | \
while read line; \
do if [ "`echo $line | perl -0777 -pe 's/[^a-zA-Z\s]//g' | aspell clean`" \
!= "`echo $line | perl -0777 -pe 's/[^a-zA-Z\s]//g' | aspell list`" ]; \
then echo $line; fi; done
```

Here is how it goes:

- Blocks between 139's are extracted (this leaves the last block
  outside)
- Lines of 139's are deleted
- Lines are fed into "while do done" loop in which letter characters are checked against dictionary. If the line includes any words in the
  dictionary, whole line is echoed. Otherwise it is deleted.

Note: Proper aspell dictionary must have been installed

Comment: Thanks Serhat for your reply. I figured out a way to do this. The blocks of text were luckily aligned so that a little tinkering allowed me to replace every 2nd, 4th, 6th, etc.. occurrence of 139 by 391. After that it was a simple sed Command  as shown here                                          sed -n "/193/,/391/p" file >> newfile       which gave the desired output. Thanks again all... and wish you all a very happy and productive new year.

Comment: Thanks for your best wishes, the same from me. I'm glad you did it.